# Как закрыть доступ к домену, если его открывают через поддомены MAIL, POP, SMTP

Tags: vds

При запросе mail.site.ru открывается sait.ru или другой сайт, на этом серваке (вдс). Тоже самое происходит и с другими поддоменами, например smtp.site.ru или pop.site.ru

Как можно сделать, чтобы данные поддомены были неактивны из браузера или просто был редирект ? А то в ПС уже дубли полезли

Comment: Отредактировать настройки вашего веб-сервера, отключив в нём обработку ненужных поддоменов.

Comment: а точнее, что нужно редактировать ?

Comment: Точнее зависит от ваших текущих настроек вашего веб-сервера.